# UniVerse PHANTOM command

Tags: universe

I program in UniVerse BASIC and VB6 (using UniObjects). Somehow I have become the only person onsite who cannot run a PHANTOM command. Whether it is called from VB6 or from BASIC, it fails. At TCL I get "Unable to create PHANTOM process." but only if I log in with my domain ID. If I use another ID it runs. And it is only on one host. I used to be able to run PHANTOM commands. Neither local support nor Rocket have an idea. If everyone could not run PHANTOMS, there is a solution for that.
Has anyone ever come across this? Does anyone have an idea?
Your thoughts appreciated.
Jef4974

Searched my registry looking for PHANTOM and my login name - nothing found that seemed involved. Don't know what else to look for in there. Looked in the UniVerse database to see if there is a setting I may have offended. Again nothing looked like it has a grudge against me. As I said support back to and including Rocket have no idea. The Internet search sent me in all sorts of directions but I still cannot PHANTOM.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry late to the party, is it stil an issue, did you get a solution?
I haven't come across that issue myself and try to avoid Phantom as it has proven quirky. Which OS is your Phantom targetting?

At my last site we used an alternative called 'Screen' on Solaris then more laterly Linux for the last ten years, it is much more powerful than Phantom as you can fire up many jobs on the server to run in the background then connect to them as a user to view or even debug. Great for test environments but also known in production under extreme conditions.
There are alternatives of course and you may be wedded to Phantom already but here's the linux link https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/
For reference every end of day 'batch run' would fire up hundreds of these which in turn fired up hundreds more, sometimes ten+ layers deep in a mission critical environment. So we found it to be very reliable. cheers

Comment: Hi Andy,
Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately we are using MS Windows, so we have no Screen to use.
The issue is that my login to the UniVerse server has had a setting changed somewhere in UniVerse that has locked out access to the Phantom process. At present I am the only user who cannot run Phantom. So far our supplier has no idea what is preventing the use of Phantom. I have searched for my name in the database but have not found anything.
Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).